# Select a date in my time zone when database is in UTC with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I want to select a day in my timezone for example:

from the 2021-09-09 00:00 +02 to 2021-09-10 00:00 +02. But the following code:

```
set timezone TO 'Europe/Berlin';
SELECT TIMESTAMP::timestamptz,sensor_id,value
FROM my_table
WHERE sensor_id IN (1,2,3)
AND TIMESTAMP > '2021-09-09' AND TIMESTAMP < '2021-09-10' 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
```

gives me the right values but with wrong timezone for example first rows are:

```
timestamp,sensor_id,value
2021-09-09 02:00 +02,1,21
2021-09-09 02:00 +02,2,34
2021-09-09 02:00 +02,3,54
```

but should be 2021-09-09 00:00 +02 or 2021-09-08 22:00 +00

The problem is bigger when the difference with utc changes between winter and summer

Anybony can help me?

PostgreSQL v.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'CETDST',sensor_id,value
FROM my_table
WHERE sensor_id IN (1,2,3)
AND TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CETDST' > '2021-09-09'
AND TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CETDST' < '2021-09-10' 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Whoops sorry. You can try "CETDST" (Central European Daylight Savings Time). I am not 100% sure if it does, but i thinks it observes wether it's summer or winter time.

Comment: write the full query because looking deeper doesn't seem to work (AT TIME ZONE has to be written after timestamptz)

Comment: SELECT TIMESTAMP::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE "CETDST",sensor_id,value
FROM my_table
WHERE sensor_id IN (1,2,3)
AND timestamptz > '2021-09-09' AND timestamptz < '2021-09-10' 
ORDER BY timestamptz

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. I thoght "TIMESTAMP" was the type of the column. Let me take another look.

Comment: I have edited the code above.

Comment: ok you intuition is good add AT TIME ZONE after the AND. Now I have to find the right zone because this is 2h behind and should be 1h

Comment: For Berlin it should either be 'CETDST' or 'METDST'. Middle/Central European Daylight Savings Time. But you can also try Eastern 'EETDST'

Comment: you are right casue is 1 h now but in winter were 2h. Your aswer is correct well done

Comment: `AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'` works fine on my server (I have no idea if it's universally available).